# Explicitly defaulting a templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, default-constructor

I tried to make *default constructor* `= default;` conditionally depending on class template argument's property using following technique:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

template< typename T >
struct identity
{

};

template< typename T >
struct has_property
    : std::false_type
{

};

template< typename T >
struct S
{
    template< typename X = T,
              typename = std::enable_if_t< !has_property< X >::value > >
    S(identity< X > = {})
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    template< typename X = T,
              typename = std::enable_if_t< has_property< X >::value > >
#if 0
    S() = default;
#else
    S()
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
#endif
};

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<>
struct has_property< B >
    : std::true_type
{

};

int main()
{
    S< A >{};
    S< B >{};
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But for `#if 1` it gives an error:

```
main.cpp:32:11: error: only special member functions may be defaulted
    S() = default;
          ^
```

Is not `template< ... > S()` a declaration of a *default constructor* for `S`?

Can I implement such a dispatching using coming *Concepts* in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is covered by [dcl.fct.def.default]:

> A function that is explicitly defaulted shall:
>
> - be a special member function,
> - have the same declared function type (except for possibly differing ref-qualifiers and except that in the case of a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be “reference to non-const T”, where T is the name of the member function’s class) as if it had been implicitly declared,

In your case, the implicitly-declared default constructor would not have been a function template,  so you cannot explicitly default it.

GCC 5.x gives the error for your code, `error: a template cannot be defaulted`.

Comment: @Orient OK. I am not 100% sure about this answer, it would have been nice if the standard did explicitly say "a template cannot be defaulted" although I can't find such text.   I'm not completely sure what "declared function type" means for a function template.

Comment: @Orient were you going to edit your post to remove `constexpr` ?

Comment: @Orient ok, it didn't show up until some time after I made that comment